# how to generate kubernetes yml file with io.fabric8?

Tags: kubernetes, fabric8

I want generate kubernetes manifest files with fabric8. please help me.

```
@EnableKubernetesMockClient
public class KubernetesClientTests {
    KubernetesClient client;

    @Test
    public void testCreateManifest() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(client);
        //CREATE
        Pod pod = client.pods().inNamespace("ns1").resource(new   PodBuilder().withNewMetadata().withName("pod1").endMetadata().build())
                .create();
        Assert.assertNotNull(pod);
        //READ
        //TODO, generate manifest file???

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Serialization.asYaml()` method to convert object to YAML string and `Serialization.asJson()` method to convert object to JSON string:

I've tested this code on [KubernetesClient v6.7.2](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/releases/tag/v6.7.2) and it seems to be working okay:

```java
try (KubernetesClient k8s = new KubernetesClientBuilder().build()) {
  Pod pod = k8s.pods()
      .inNamespace("default")
      .withName("excj496")
      .get();
  // Get YAML string
  System.out.println(Serialization.asYaml(pod));
  // Get JSON string
  System.out.println(Serialization.asJson(pod));
}
```

Comment: @h.tayebi: Did it work for you use case?

Comment: It works for me.
#--------------- my unit test ------------------
PodBuilder podBuilder = new PodBuilder().withNewMetadata()
                .withName("pod1")
                .withNamespace("n1")
                .endMetadata()
                .withNewSpec()
                .addNewContainer()
                .withName("nginx")
                .withImage("nginx:v1.2.3")
                .endContainer()
                .endSpec();
        Pod pod = client.pods().resource(podBuilder.build()).create();
        System.out.println(Serialization.asYaml(pod));

Comment: If you're satisfied with the answer, Could you please mark it as accepted?